# Tomcat multiple instances of WebAppClassLoader getting created and therefore high Resident memory usage

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, classloader, tomcat8

**Tomcat version:** apache-tomcat-8.0.21
**OS:** Ubuntu
**Java version :** 8
**Tool:** VisualVM

On starting the tomcat, resident memory usage starts in mbs and reaches around 6-7gb (10gb virtual memory). Heap is only around 700mb.

My understanding is that each of the web application will have only one associated `WebAppClassLoader`.

We have 12 web applications including docs examples etc. I used VisualVM tool to analyse and found that there were 29 instances of  `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader` in the profiler and heapdump.

While starting the tomcat, it starts with 12 instances of `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader` but gradually keeps increasing the instance count and also the memory usage(metaspace) increases and after sometime tomcat crashes because of `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace`. We have not defined metaspace limit. And FYI we did not do any reload webapp operation.

Why is the number of instances of `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader` increasing?

I was suspecting of may be classloader leaks and found this [link](https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/)?
But I am unable to find an instance of WebAppClassLoader with property started as false.

Regarding memory leaks, heap memory did not vary much and was within acceptable limits.

Comment: Were any of the web applications restarted or redeployed, or are other lifecycle events for the applications being reported?

Comment: @JonahB nope. Did not restart or redeploy.

Comment: Copies of the class loader can be made for purposes of persistence or instrumentation, for instance with copyWithoutTransformers().

Comment: @JonahB ok. i have edited my post. why there is high memory usage? Eventually we are facing OutOfMemory scenario. Want to know if there are any problems with application war or not.

Comment: Do you found solution for this problem?